# MaxyBy return multiple item from the list

Tags: c#, list, sorting, max, ienumerable

How can I return multiple item from the list that has the same value?
I am using maxBy to return item with the highest value on a property. Highest value is 5 and i know there are two items in the list with that. But it only returns 1 item back. I would like it to return both items.

itemA point = 5, itemB point = 5, itemC point = 4

```
var teamWithHighestPoint = _unsortedLeagueTable.MaxBy(t => t.Points);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get all the elements with the maximum score:

```
var maxPoints = _unsortedLeagueTable.Max(t => t.Points);
var teamWithHighestPoint = _unsortedLeagueTable.Where(t => t.Points == maxPoints);
```